# Administration menu - How to remove the number of users + search bar

Tags: 7

Out of the blue, our administration menu now shows a number like `192/7` on the right side and a search bar.

[image]

Does anyone know what causes these items to appear on the administration menu? And how can I remove them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to `admin/config/administration/admin_menu` Under the Plugins tab uncheck *Search bar* and *Account links* then click Save configuration